# SQL Get values from parent and child table

Tags: sql-server

```
table 1                                                                    
.........

p_id | p_name| p_age|p_gender     

101  | Aniyan| 27   | male     


table2 
.......                                     

c_id |p_id | c_name |c_age | c_gender                                                 
201  | 101 | Devraj | 35   |  male                         
202  | 101 | Anisha | 20   | female                                      
203  | 101 | Deepak | 50   | male
```

i need to get answer like this ,

```
name  |  age  | gender                                  

Aniyan| 27    | male                           
Devraj| 35    | male                                                      
Anisha| 20    | female                                                           
Deepak| 50    | male
```

I need merging the table.. any help is appreciable.Table 1 contains the main person who is the guardian or something . Table 2 is the members of same booking. i need to keep it in different table according to my project . so i am waiting...sorry i don't have much reputation to post it as a pic.

Comment: try using `union` between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `UNION`, as currently defined:

```
SELECT p_name AS Name, p_age AS Age, p_gender AS Gender FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT c_name AS Name, c_age AS Age, c_gender AS Gender FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will combine the results from both tables

```
select p_name as name, p_age as age, p_gender as gender
from table1
union
select c_name as name, c_age as age, c_gender as gender
from table2
```

Comment: great.. i will try on this